# Cannot Recognize Speech Error: Error occurred while processing 'audio.wav'. Invalid WAV header in file, RIFF was not found

Tags: node.js, azure, whatsapp, azure-cognitive-services, azure-speech

I captured one voice message from WhatsApp and it saved as wav file using node js. But I pass this wav file for speech translation using azure speech to text JavaScript sdk it not showing anything and also try this file into demo app also, in azure demo app([azure demo app](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/speech-to-text/#overview)) I got error "Cannot Recognize Speech Error: Error occurred while processing 'audio.wav'. Invalid WAV header in file, RIFF was not found".

[converted audio file information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlqmH.jpg)

Encoding code

```
            var encoder = new base64.Base64Encode();
            var b64s = request(options).pipe(encoder);
            var strBase64 = yield getStream(b64s);
            const fs = require('fs');
            const wavUrl = 'data:audio/wav;codecs=pcm;base64,' + strBase64;
            const buffer = Buffer.from(wavUrl.split('base64,')[1], // only use encoded data after "base64,"
            'base64');
            fs.writeFileSync('./audio.wav', buffer);
```

Is any one have any idea about this

Answer (score 1):

- This problem may occur because of a WAV header size limit in the JavaScript SDK.
  You can pull request to raise this limit [microsoft/cognitive-services-speech-sdk-js#328](https://github.com/microsoft/cognitive-services-speech-sdk-js/pull/328)
- Or in some cases you can solve it by simply converting the audio sample rate from 48kHz to 16kHz.
- Refer this [Github link](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/issues/962) for more information